# Write method that takes/returns enum constants of any enum

Tags: java, generics, enums

When I store a configuration enum, this is easy as long as it is type-bound to, say, a special enum type `MyEnum`:

```
void storeMyEnumValue(MyEnum value) {
    String valueString = value.name();
    // Store valueString somewhere
}

MyEnum loadMyEnumValue(MyEnum fallbackValue) {
    // Load valueString from somewhere
    try {
        return MyEnum.valueOf(valueString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return fallbackValue;
    }
}
```

But what if I want to generalize that and have a set of `store`/`load` methods for any type of enum?

```
void storeAnyEnumValue(??? value) {
    // The same as before
}

??? loadAnyEnumValue(??? defaultValue) {
    // The same as before
}
```

So as you can see, the question is mainly how to handle "objects of the type enum constant" in general.

Comment: [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) is base class for all enumeration types, you can use that.

Comment: You are calling a static method on `MyEnum`, you would have to inject that.

Comment: I thought of that, but then I would get an `Enum` from the `loadAnyEnumValue` function, no matter what type my argument has, or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Use generics, see my answer

Comment: I now really have the problem, which one of the -- now identical -- answers to accept.

Comment: You accepted the right one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the store method, you can just use an instance of `Enum<?>`. There is no advantage to a type variable here.

```
void storeAnyEnumValue(Enum<?> value) {
    // The same as before
}
```

For the load method, you want the return type to be of the same type as the `defaultValue`, so you do need a type variable here:

```
<E extends Enum<E>> E loadAnyEnumValue(E defaultValue) {
    // The same as before
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
void storeAnyEnumValue(Enum<?> value) {
    // The same as before
}

<T extends Enum<T>> T loadAnyEnumValue(T defaultValue) {
    // Not exactly the same as before
}
```

Comment: `<T extends Enum<T>>`: don't use raw types.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the implementation of the second method is *not* the same as before.

Comment: Good point, would use `(T) Enum.valueOf(defaultValue.getDeclaringClass(), valueString)`

Comment: You don’t need that unchecked cast `(T)`, the expression `Enum.valueOf(defaultValue.getDeclaringClass(), valueString)` does already return the right type when being used in a generic context like `<T extends Enum<T>> T loadAnyEnumValue(T defaultValue) { return …; }`