# Write method that takes/returns enum constants of any enum BY CLASS

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am getting the generics mixed up again...

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44703605/6403504), I've written methods to store and retrieve Enum values, not tied to a specific enum class:

```
public static void storeEnum(Enum<?> enumValue) {
    // Store it somehow
}

public static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum(E defaultValue) {
    String valueString = // get it somehow
    try {
        return (E) Enum.valueOf(defaultValue.getDeclaringClass(), valueString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

**But now I do not want to have any default value any more, I want to have `null` in case of no luck!**

First attempt:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum(Class<? extends Enum> enumClass) {
    String valueString = // get it somehow
    try {
        return (E) Enum.valueOf(enumClass, valueString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This compiles, but when I want to get a stored `MyCoolEnum`, the line `MyCoolEnum mci = getEnum(MyCoolEnum.class);` breaks the (Maven) compile run: `incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible upper bounds java.lang.Enum<E>,MyCoolEnum`.

Of course, this comes from the `?`. But how can I infer the type from the class?

- `(Class<E extends Enum> enumClass)` is not valid.
- `(Class<Enum<E>> enumClass)` breaks the `valueOf` (`The inferred type Enum<E> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Enum<T>>`).

Comment: Returning [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) rather than `null` would help prevent `NullPointerException`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not reproduce your first error, but as an alternative, you should be able to use `Class<E>` i.e.:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum(Class<E> enumClass) {
    String valueString = // get it somehow
    try {
        return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, valueString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Note that you can also drop the cast)